# Insert textbox value into Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Being an amateur in Access and VBA, I've hit a wall with the following...

In MS Access 2007, I have the following query:

```
SELECT .... WHERE format(NZ(l_f_date),'yyyy-mm-dd')<=**'2012-04-03'**);
```

I have shortened it a bit of course.

The database has approx 20 queries that need to be run on a daily basis.  I have created 4 macros to run groups of queries in the manner that I need them to be run. The problem is that in every one of those queries I first have to change the date (like in the upper query). I am looking for the way to automate it a bit more.

I have an idea to create a Form, place a button for every macro on it and 2 textbox-es to enter the 2 dates I need. Now, I need those dates to appear in the bolded part. As I think about it, I have 2 options:

- Create a temporary table in the database to store those two dates and pull those 2 fields in my queries.
- Insert the value of the textbox somehow directly into the bolded part of the query.

I think I can manage the first solution, but the second one is making my head hurt.

Can you help?

---

SQL from comment

```
select proc_desc,count(s) as broj 
into upit3 
from ( select distinct a.case_id as s,
          a.org_case_id,a.act_date as day,d.prod_id,d.prod_desc,
          c.fname,c.dpd,c.due_amount,proc_id,proc_desc 
       from actions_b as a, cases_old_b as c,processes_b as p,
            product_dict_b as d 
       where a.org_case_id=c.[org_ case_id] 
       and a.act_date=Forms!Form!Text10 and d.prod_id=c.product 
       and p.proc_id=c.process and not_lead=1 ) 
group by proc_desc order by proc_desc;
```

OK, sample data....

In x.dates, value is exactly like this: **03.04.2012**
In a.act_date value is like this: **01.07.2011 13:53:56**

so if its not possible with this values as they are, is it possible to use a LIKE statement in the query? Pseudo:  `WHERE a.act_date LIKE x.date%`
If its possible, how to use it? i am a novice in sql and access queries... I google but sometimes, like this time, i get stuck.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i decided to create a simple 2-column table in my database that will be used just for storing yesterdays and todays date... i added 2 text-boxes to a form, 1 button and added the next procedure to the button:

```
Private Sub Command25_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Datumi"
Dim tbl As Recordset
Set tbl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Datumi")
tbl.AddNew
tbl!brojka = "1"
tbl!datum = Text8.Value
tbl.Update
tbl.AddNew
tbl!brojka = "2"
tbl!datum = Text10.Value
tbl.Update
End Sub
```

As you can see, the click on the button will clear the table and store new values into 2 rows... row 1 is yesterday, row 2 is today...

And after that im pulling the values from that table like this:

```
... where x.brojka=1 and format(a.act_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')=format(x.datum,'yyyy-mm-dd') ...
```

I'm sure it can be done better but this one works for me...

Answer (score 1):

This structure:

```
SELECT .... WHERE format(NZ(l_f_date),'yyyy-mm-dd')<='2012-04-03');
```

Is not a good idea. The general rule is to try and stick to field (column) names on the left side of the equals. So

```
SELECT .... WHERE l_f_date <=#2012-04-03#
```

Nulls will not be included and I hope your dates *are* dates and not strings.

Next add the form:

```
SELECT .... WHERE l_f_date <= Forms!TheNameOfTheForm!TheNameOfTheTextbox
```

**EDIT re comments**

You are using the query design window, yes? Please try this test query:

```
SELECT a.case_id, a.act_date
FROM actions_b AS a
WHERE a.act_date=Forms!Form!Text10
```

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply. the dates ARE actualy dates. but the above query returns empty... i wrote it like this:

and a.act_date=[Forms]![Form]![Text10]

or

and a.act_date=Forms!Form!Text10

Access doesnt report any errors but there are no results after the query.

Comment: Which query returns empty? Does the query where you use an actual date work? Is the form open when you run the query?

Comment: Another thing - can you edit your post to include the SQL for your query?

Comment: Please try the test query above and see what it returns.

Comment: ok, i tried it and it didnt work... but now (i guess) i know why... my date in the actions_b database is in this format **2012-02-08 18:44:34** and the form field picks only the date, without the hours... i guess thats the problem, but offcourse, anotherone i dont know how to solve...

Comment: One possibility `WHERE a.act_date>=Forms!Form!Text10 AND a.act_date<Forms!Form!Text10 + 1`

Comment: Another possibility relies on the fact that all dates are numeric and time is the decimal `WHERE CDate(Int(a.act_date))=Forms!Form!Text10` This may be slower depending on your indexes.

Comment: BTW I notice you are using implied joins. You may wish to read http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx. Explicit joins are generally better for speed in MS Access.

Comment: ok, su i thought it will be easier to just put the date info into separate table because i cant make this work... and now i did this: instead of `and format(a.act_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')='2012-04-03'` i've put `and x.br=1 and CDate(Int(a.act_date))=x.date` where br and date are 2 fields in the temp table. but using those two variants, i get different results... the results without CDate are correct, su what am i doing wrong with the other one?

Comment: What is the value of x.date? Can you post some sample data? To do this, edit your post above, do not post a comment.

Comment: solved the problem. i will share the solution with you all tuesday when i get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this problem with :
[Software: MS Access 2013]

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Inventory Transactions] ([Product ID], [Order ID])" _
& "VALUES ( " & Me.Product_ID & ", " & Me.Order_ID & ")"
```